# Jupyter notebook 403 GET API error while launching in terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel

[W 04:46:14.287 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1706154374276 (127.0.0.1) 0.550000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.288 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.288 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1706154374281 (127.0.0.1) 1.130000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1706154374280 (127.0.0.1) 1.560000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1706154374281 (127.0.0.1) 1.640000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.289 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1706154374281 (127.0.0.1) 1.730000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.290 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.290 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1706154374281 (127.0.0.1) 1.820000ms referer=None
[W 04:46:14.290 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 04:46:14.290 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1706154374286 (127.0.0.1) 1.510000ms referer=None
I was just hosting the jupyter notebook local normally ysterday, then woke up today. It is becoming everytime I open terminal, jupyter notebook, this became the error. It doesnt matter where I started the jupyter notebook, I will always get this error.

while in line while running one line of notebook
it gives error in various format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6FeJ.png)

Can some one help me what is going on

tried with gpt,

Update pip:
Ensure that you have the latest version of pip by running the following command:

bash

pip install --upgrade pip

Install or Upgrade Dependencies:
Address the specific dependencies mentioned in the error. In this case, you can try installing the required versions of 'pyqt5' and 'pyqtwebengine':

bash

pip install pyqt5==5.12 pyqtwebengine==5.12

Resolve nbclassic Version:
The conflict with 'nbclassic' can be resolved by installing the compatible version:

bash

pip install nbclassic~=0.2

Upgrade or Reinstall Packages:
After addressing the specific conflicts, you may need to upgrade or reinstall the affected packages. For example:

bash

pip install --upgrade spyder jupyterlab

---

but none of that works,

I have also tried  % conda update jupyter
here is my specs

python --version
Python 3.9.18

pip list  |grep jupyter
jupyter                               1.0.0
jupyter-client                        6.1.12
jupyter-console                       6.4.0
jupyter_core                          5.5.0
jupyter-server                        1.13.5
jupyterlab                            3.3.2
jupyterlab-pygments                   0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                     2.10.3
jupyterlab-widgets                    3.0.9

pip list |grep ^nb
nbclassic                             0.5.5
nbclient                              0.5.3
nbconvert                             5.5.0
nbformat                              5.9.2

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/2009 << please read this

Comment: It doesnt looks like the issue, because I had the issues first, then I went for the solution of thier variant 1 and 2 cases 

but I dont quite get why my terminal   jupyter notebook is still in the status of 403 GET error ... but then I use VSC and run a line of the .ipynb then it works...?!

Answer (score 0):

Try Hard reload with clearing cache if on chrome or firefox

Comment: I changed default brower from safari to chrome. and it was the same error. but somehow after a while, although 403 error still exist, I am open to run the jupyter notebook with the error